# mongodb lookup when local field is array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, lookup

```
{
    university : "Canada University",
    courses : [
        {name : "ABC"},
        {name : "xyz"}
    ]
}
```

Here courses field for me is local field

Answer (score 0):

You have to **normalize** your collection by **Unwinding** the collection where **localField** is an array.

So it would like this:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
{$unwind: "courses"},
{$lookup:{
      from:"collection2",
      localField: "courses.name",
      foreignField: "collection2field",
      as:"results"

 }}

])
```